# What is the language Ashdudis?

Tags: language, ezra-nechemya

[This Artscroll *sidur*](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/issrh.html) mentions "Ashdudis" in its introduction. This language being spoken by a portion of the Jewish population at the time of Ezra is apparently attested by [*Nechemya* 13:24](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Nehemiah.13.24?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), although there it is called "AshdOdis". Is a language spoken exclusively in Ashdod attested anywhere else? Is this a reference to another known language?

Comment: Perhaps http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philistine_language?

Comment: Google found this: "an Assyrian dialect" http://books.google.com/books?id=Vk6BLlUCwMsC&lpg=PA52&ots=ZmvnJAXGok&dq=Ashdudis&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q=Ashdudis&f=false

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashdod#Antiquity) has: "In the Book of Nehemiah, the *Ashdodites* seem to represent the whole nation of the Philistines in the sixth century BCE,[14] the *speech of Ashdod* (which the younger generation of the Jews are described as adopting) would simply be the general Philistine dialect. Hugo Winckler explains the use of that name by the fact that Ashdod was the nearest of the Philistine cities to Jerusalem.[15]" 14: "at 13:23,24". 15: "*Geschichte Israels*. 1898. p. 224"

Comment: Perhaps [Isaiah 19:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1019.htm#18)?

Comment: Scholars offer various guesses, all inconclusive, about the identity of Ashdodith. It seems that it is viewed as either vestigial Phoenician or a local dialect of Aramaic.